# Entity Framework context not refreshing

Tags: c#, asp.net, frameworks, entity, blazor

Good morning. I'm using Blazor 3 preview 9. Actually I can't refresh my context without reloading the entire page with F5. I'm already using separated contexts. If I remove a row with:

```
 using (var context = new PlutoneContext())
            {
                context.Azienda.Remove(azienda);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
```

and later I reload data with

```
 using (var context = new PlutoneContext())
            {
                var query = context.Azienda.AsNoTracking().ToList().Where(a =>
                                                            a.Codice.ContainsCaseInsensitive(_filtroCodice) &&
                                                            a.RagioneSociale.ContainsCaseInsensitive(_filtroRagioneSociale) &&
                                                            a.PartitaIva.ContainsCaseInsensitive(_filtroPartitaIva) &&
                                                            a.CodiceFiscale.ContainsCaseInsensitive(_filtroCodiceFiscale) &&
                                                            a.Telefono.ContainsCaseInsensitive(_filtroTelefono) &&
                                                            a.Email.ContainsCaseInsensitive(_filtroEmail)).ToList();

                if (_direzioneOrdinamento == DirezioneOrdinamento.Ascendente)
                    query = query.OrderBy(a => a.GetType().GetProperty(_colonnaOrdinamento).GetValue(a, null)).ToList();
                else
                    query = query.OrderByDescending(a => a.GetType().GetProperty(_colonnaOrdinamento).GetValue(a, null)).ToList();

                _numeroRighe = query.Count;
                _numeroPagine = query.Count() / 10;
                if (query.Count() % 10 != 0) _numeroPagine++;

                _aziende = query.Skip((_pagina - 1) * 10).Take(10).ToList();
            }
```

the deleted row is still there. But I'm already disposing and using 2 contexts. And also I've disblabled caching with AsNoTracking().

How can I fix it?

**Update 1**

```
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        CaricaTabella();
    }

    private void CaricaTabella()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = new PlutoneContext())
            {
                var query = context.Azienda.AsNoTracking().ToList().Where(a => 
                                                            a.Codice.ContainsCaseInsensitive(_filtroCodice) &&
                                                            a.RagioneSociale.ContainsCaseInsensitive(_filtroRagioneSociale) &&
                                                            a.PartitaIva.ContainsCaseInsensitive(_filtroPartitaIva) &&
                                                            a.CodiceFiscale.ContainsCaseInsensitive(_filtroCodiceFiscale) &&
                                                            a.Telefono.ContainsCaseInsensitive(_filtroTelefono) &&
                                                            a.Email.ContainsCaseInsensitive(_filtroEmail)).ToList();

                if (_direzioneOrdinamento == DirezioneOrdinamento.Ascendente)
                    query = query.OrderBy(a => a.GetType().GetProperty(_colonnaOrdinamento).GetValue(a, null)).ToList();
                else
                    query = query.OrderByDescending(a => a.GetType().GetProperty(_colonnaOrdinamento).GetValue(a, null)).ToList();

                _numeroRighe = query.Count;
                _numeroPagine = query.Count() / 10;
                if (query.Count() % 10 != 0) _numeroPagine++;

                _aziende = query.Skip((_pagina - 1) * 10).Take(10).ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _caricamento = false;
        }

        _caricamento = false;
    }

    private void Ordina(string colonna)
    {
        if (_colonnaOrdinamento != colonna)
        {
            _colonnaOrdinamento = colonna;
            _direzioneOrdinamento = DirezioneOrdinamento.Ascendente;

            CaricaTabella();
        }
        else
        {
            if (_direzioneOrdinamento == DirezioneOrdinamento.Ascendente)
                _direzioneOrdinamento = DirezioneOrdinamento.Discendente;
            else
                _direzioneOrdinamento = DirezioneOrdinamento.Ascendente;

            CaricaTabella();
        }
    }

    private async void Cancella(Azienda azienda)
    {
        if (!(await JavaScriptInterop.MessageBoxConferma("Vuoi davvero cancellare l'azienda " + azienda.RagioneSociale + "?")))
            return;

        try
        {
            using (var context = new PlutoneContext())
            {
                context.Azienda.Remove(azienda);
                context.SaveChanges();
                StateHasChanged();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await JavaScriptInterop.MessageBox("Si è verificato un errore durante la cancellazione dell'azienda");
            return;
        }

        CaricaTabella();
    }
```

**Update 2**

```
@foreach (var azienda in _aziende)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@azienda.Codice</td>
                            <td>@azienda.RagioneSociale</td>
                            <td>@azienda.PartitaIva</td>
                            <td>@azienda.CodiceFiscale</td>
                            <td>@azienda.Email</td>
                            <td>@azienda.Telefono</td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="(() => Modifica(azienda))"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                                <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="(() => Cancella(azienda))"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
```

**Update 3**
I've done in this way but nothing changed.

```
using (var context = new PlutoneContext())
            {
                var a = context.Azienda.Find(azienda.Codice);
                if (a != null)
                {
                    context.Azienda.Remove(a);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
                StateHasChanged();
            }
```

Comment: "and later I reload data"  - how much later?  It would help to see how you call these async methods here.

Comment: As a diagnostic, ` int n = await context.SaveChangesAsync();` and verify that `n == 1`

Comment: @HenkHolterman Immediately after executing the remove command. The line is removed, because when I reload the window, the deleted row is missing.

Comment: Show the code for "Immediately after". This smells like an async issue.

Comment: Full code uploaded :-)

Comment: Not full enough... )-:  That `Cancella()` is an `async void`, a likely cause for your problem. But I can't see how you call it.

Comment: From a button :-) I've uploaded the code.

Answer (score 0):

Good day sir. Hard to tell from this context.
Maybe here

```
            {
                context.Azienda.Remove(azienda);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
```

the `azienda` is not tracked? This also could be a method with `async void` declaration in the call above.

For me the using state feels like a code smell. You could use the (build in) DI that handles the lifetime of the DbContext.

Btw. in the second part you are loading every data into the memory. `context.Azienda.AsNoTracking().ToList()` and after that you are applying the filtering on the loaded data set and not on the SQL server it self. In a large data set this may end up eating a lot of memory and the query evaluation will be slow.

Comment: I'm checking if the object is tracked or not. About performances, yes, I know that client execution could lead to slowness. But if I don't do this, I receive an exception at runtime saying that "LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()"

Comment: Focusing on the question, how do you tell the UI (blazor component) that something changed? Maybe you messed up the two way binding or a simple call in the component ```StateHasChanged()``` would be enough

Comment: Just tried StateHasChanged(), it doesn't work. But, after a second delet, the first row disappears and I've the same problem with the second row :-D